# sentinal-controlled loops + arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm *very* new to programming, and I am trying to create a program that that will ask the user in a sentinel-controlled loop to enter words.
After all words are entered, the program should display them in alphabetical order along with the original order side by side.

Right now I'm trying to create a copy of the userWords array (max 20) that has the exact length of the user input, so that it can be sorted (can't sort nulls).

I am having problems.
Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlphabeticalWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0;
        String [] userWords= new String[20];
        String[] myCopyArray=getArrayCopy(userWords);
        myCopyArray[counter];


        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        for (counter=0; counter< userWords.length; counter++){
            System.out.println("Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop");
            while (input.hasNext()){
                userWords[counter]=input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop");
                counter++;
            }
        }
                //System.arraycopy(userWords);

                //Arrays.sort(userWords);
                //printArrayElements(userWords);
    }

    public static void printArrayElements( String[] anyArray){
        for(int index=0; index< anyArray.length; index++){
            System.out.println(anyArray[index]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem you're having is?

Comment: What is `getArrayCopy` something you written??

Comment: You can use `System.arraycopy( userWords, 0, myCopyArray, 0, userWords.length );` to copy arrays.

Comment: ankur-singhal Thank you very much for the help!  I completely understand the changes that you made, and they make everything much clearer.        To answer the comments- getArrayCopy is a program that we wrote in class to make a true copy. It was done for int type, but i converted it to String.  System.arraycopy is something that I originally tried to use, but wasn't able to figure out the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here.

Changes Done

1.) No need for while loop, when for loop is being used.

2.) used `System.arraycopy(userWords, 0, newArray, 0, userWords.length);` to copy an array.

3.) Two Arrays maintained, original and copied, sorting done on copied array.

4.) Lastly both arrays printed .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0;
        String[] userWords = new String[5];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (counter = 0; counter < userWords.length; counter++) {
            System.out
                    .println("Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop" + counter);
            userWords[counter] = input.nextLine();
        }
        String[] myCopyArray = getArrayCopy(userWords);
        Arrays.sort(myCopyArray);

        printArrayElements(userWords, myCopyArray);
    }

    private static String[] getArrayCopy(String[] userWords) {
        String[] newArray = new String[userWords.length];
        System.arraycopy(userWords, 0, newArray, 0, userWords.length);
        return newArray;
    }

    public static void printArrayElements(String[] originalArray,
            String[] sortedArray) {
        for (int index = 0; index < originalArray.length; index++) {
            System.out.println(originalArray[index] + " :: "
                    + sortedArray[index]);
        }

    }
```

**Output**

```
Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop0
asd
Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop1
asda
Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop2
werw
Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop3
efgv
Please enter a word or Crl-D to stop4
qe
asd :: asd
asda :: asda
werw :: efgv
efgv :: qe
qe :: werw
```